# Cython using SIMD intrinsic crashes

Tags: python, cython, simd, avx2

I am trying to use Cython for SIMD (AVX2). My CPU does support it. I found this code in here that does SSE.

https://github.com/Technologicat/cython-sse-example

So I made this for AVX called avx_test5.pyx

```
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc, free, calloc
cdef extern from "immintrin.h":  # in this example, we use AVX2
    ctypedef float  __m256
    __m256 _mm256_loadu_ps (float *__P) nogil  
    __m256 _mm256_add_ps   (__m256 __A, __m256 __B) nogil
    __m256 _mm256_mul_ps   (__m256 __A, __m256 __B) nogil
    __m256 _mm256_fmadd_ps (__m256 __A, __m256 __B, __m256 __C) nogil
    void   _mm256_store_ps (float *__P, __m256 __A) nogil  

cdef void Example_v1 (float *A, float *B, float *C) :
    ### this example for A and B having exactly 8 elements    
    cdef:
        __m256 mA, mB, mC
        float[8] out1, out2
        int i

    with nogil:
        mA = _mm256_loadu_ps( &A[0] )
        mB = _mm256_loadu_ps( &B[0] )
        mC = _mm256_loadu_ps( &C[0] )
        _mm256_store_ps( &out1[0], _mm256_add_ps  ( mA, mB ) )
        _mm256_store_ps( &out2[0], _mm256_fmadd_ps( mA, mB, mC ) )

    for i in range(8):
        print( "out1  out2 : ", i, out1[i], out2[i], sep=", " ) 

def run1(float [::1] A, float [::1] B, float [::1] C):
    Example_v1( &A[0] , &B[0] , &C[0] )
```

In my python code, I call them:

```
import numpy as np

print ("Hello World")
from avx_test7 import run1 

np.random.seed(1)
A =        np.ones(8 , dtype=np.float32)
B = np.random.rand(8).astype(np.float32)
C = np.random.rand(8).astype(np.float32)

print ( A + B)
print ( A * B + C)
run1(A, B, C)
```

When I ran them, my spyder just crashed or stuck. No error messages, nothing and just hang, although I can restart kernel.

I've scan thru the cython file many times and do not see anything done wrong. Anybody can help with this ? I used MSVC 2017 compiler and cython file compiled ok.

Comment: I don't know Cython, but it appears you call `free(out1)` on local array variables (automatic storage), not dynamically allocated.  That would break in normal C.  Also, you do that *before* looping over them which looks very wrong.  If that's not it, run your code under a debugger to see where it crashes.

Comment: opps, sorry, the "free" was added when thing already have problem and the print was commented out at the time. I reopen it just to make it look like Example_v1 was producing something that can check, i'll edit it a bit.

Comment: It appears to work for me on GCC on Linux. Obviously that may not help you much. I did have to change CFLAGS to `-march=native` to get it to compile - I don't know if there's a similar change needed for MSVC

Comment: @DavidW:  GCC won't emit AVX instructions (even from intrinsics) without `-mavx`.  MSVC will let you do that (but doesn't *optimize* intrinsics), although `-arch:AVX` is (highly?) recommended.  This code never passes a `__m256` as a function arg (except to intrinsics), so calling-convention issues shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @OngBengSeong: Ok, so after fixing that bug, use a debugger to find out where it hangs or crashes.

Comment: Can you try `_mm256_storeu_ps` instead of `_mm256_store_ps`? Your data is probably only aligned to 16 bytes.

Comment: @chtz is probably right: stack pointer is only 16byte aligned on Win64, your chances to crash are 50%, because out1, out2 don't have to be 32byte aligned